# writing filter function using foldr?

Tags: scheme, racket, fold, filterfunction

Currently trying to write a filter function that takes a list of procedures and a list of numbers, deletes the procedures that does not return true on every element of the list of numbers.

What I have done is the following, currently taking a single procedure and runs through the list to create a list stating whether the procedure is true or false for each element.

Using foldr, or map if required (non recursive)

```
 (define (my-filter ps xs)
    (foldr (λ (x y)
             (cons (ps x) y)) '() xs))
```

How do I delete the procedure if it has at lease one #f?

i.e. 
currently

```
> (my-filter even? '(1 2 3 4))
(#f #t #f #t)
> (my-filter even? (2 4))
(#t #t)
```

want

```
> (my-filter (list even?) '(1 2 3 4))
(list)
> (my-filter (list even?) '(2 4))
(list even?)
```

Comment: think the: > (my-filter (list even?) '(1 2 3 4)), should return: (list), typo

Comment: Does it matter that it uses `foldr` instead of `foldl` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with some wishful thinking. Say we have a know of knowing if all `xs` return `#t` for any given `f`

```
(define (my-filter fs xs)
  (foldr (λ (f y)
           (if (every? f xs)
               (cons f y)
               y))
         '()
         fs))
```

Now let's define `every?`

```
(define (every? f xs)
  (cond [(null? xs) #t]
        [(f (car xs)) (every? f (cdr xs))]
        [else #f]))
```

Let's check it out for `(list even?)`

```
(my-filter (list even?) '(1 2 3 4)) ; ⇒ '()
(my-filter (list even?) '(2 4))     ; ⇒ '(#<procedure:even?>)
```

Let's add another test in the mix

```
(define (gt3? x) (> x 3))

(my-filter (list even? gt3?) '(2 4)) ; ⇒ '(#<procedure:even?>)
(my-filter (list even? gt3?) '(4 6)) ; ⇒ '(#<procedure:even?> #<procedure:gt3?>)
```

Cool !

---

If you want to see "pretty" procedure names instead of the `#<procedure:...>` stuff, you can map `object-name` over the resulting array

```
(map object-name (my-filter (list even? gt3?) '(4 6))) ; ⇒ '(even? gt3?)
```

> Even though `foldl` will give you a reversed output, I still think it would be better to use `foldl` in this case. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: i see, thanks so much! Quick question, how would I return the result as: (list even?) instead of (#<procedure:even?>). Cons or list doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `#<procedure:even?>` is just the string representation of the `even?` procedure

Comment: @George if you just want the string name of the procedure, you can map `object-name` over the resulting list. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this by using Racket's built-in [`andmap`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._andmap%29%29) procedure, which tests if a condition is true for all elements in a list - like this:

```
(define (my-filter ps xs)
  (foldr (lambda (f acc)
           (if (andmap f xs) ; if `f` is true for all elements in `xs`
               (cons f acc)  ; then add `f` to the accumulated output
               acc))         ; otherwise leave the accumulator alone
         '()                 ; initially the accumulator is an empty list
         ps))                ; iterate over the list of functions
```

Notice that we do not "delete" functions from the output list, instead at each step we decide whether or not we should add them to the output list.

The advantage of [`foldr`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._foldr%29%29) is that it preserves the same order as the input list, if that's not a requirement, [`foldl`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._foldl%29%29) is more efficient because internally it uses tail recursion. Either way, it works as expected:

```
(my-filter (list even?) '(1 2 3 4))
=> '()

(my-filter (list even?) '(2 4))
=> '(#<procedure:even?>)
```

Comment: Thanks! But I doubt I'm allowed to use andmap as it does almost all the work already. :D

Comment: That's a shame :( it's a nicer solution, using `andmap`. Remember it, for the day when the need arises again.

Comment: Óscar, thanks for sharing `andmap`. I was unaware of its existence.